# Find all natural number(s) $n$ such that $55\mid n^2 + 3n + 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, congruences

> Find all natural number(s) $n$ such that $55\mid n^2 + 3n + 1$

I see that $n^2+3n+1 =n^2-2n+1+5n\equiv n^2-2n+1=(n-1)^2 \pmod{5}$
I also see that $n^2+3n+1=n^2+3n-10+11=(n-2)(n+5)+11\equiv(n-2)(n+5) \pmod{11}$
After that what?

Comment: Which numbers are such that $n\equiv 1\pmod{5}$ and $n\pmod{11}\in\{2,6\}$? CRT.

Comment: $$a(n)=\frac{1}{4} \left(110 n-61+25 (-1)^n\right)$$
$6,46,61,101,116,156,171,211,226,266,\ldots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what you deduced we have $n\equiv 1 \bmod 5$ and $n\equiv 2$ or $n\equiv 6 \bmod 11$.

This tells us $n\equiv 46$ or $n\equiv 6 \bmod 55$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many solutions, in particular you have the identity
$$(55t-119)^2+3(55t-119)+1=55(55t^2-235t+251)$$which shows solutions $x=55t-119$ for each integer $t$ you choose. There are maybe other solutions out of this infinity of them.